# Passing variable JavaScript with AJAX post to PHP file, nothing happen but there is no error in console log

Tags: php, html, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to make a search form, based on the date from input field, the variable is exist when I show it with first alert. But after the first alert line, it seems nothing happen and console log don't says anything

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#find').click(function(){    

        var date = $('#date').val();
        var month = $('#month').val();
        var year = $('#year').val();
        var search = year+'-'+month+'-'+date;
        
         //alert(search); <--currently the alert stop by the comment tag , its work well if the comment tag remove      

            $.ajax({
            url:'page/report/find.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{data:search},
            success:function(data){

             $('#find_date').html(data); <-- not send value to the div id aka blank result
             alert(data);   <--not showing alert aka nothing happen
             console.log(data); <--not showing error 

            }   

            });     
    });
});

</script>
```

Below is the PHP file waiting the variable from AJAX to proccess

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR|MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);


if(isset($_POST)){

//parse_str($_POST['data'],$_POST); 

$message = $_POST['data'];

} 

echo $message;

?>
```

And below is the form

```
<form name="edit" id="edit_frm" method="post">
<table class="edit-table">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="center">
            <input type="text" id="date" size="1" value="" placeholder="date">&nbsp;-&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="month" size="1" value="" placeholder="month">&nbsp;-&nbsp;
            <input type="text" id="year" size="2" value="" placeholder="year">&nbsp;
            <input type="button" id="find" value="<< search >>" />
            <div id="find_date"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

Comment: You have typo in your javascript: change `succsess` to `success`.

Comment: @Robert : omg  I missed it, ive been looking for it all day long , thanks for checking and finding the immigrant little 's', have a good day and god bless you